# Regex capturing group overrides previous matches

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-group

Why does the regex

```
class (?<class>\w+) (?<b>\{)(?:\s*(?<method>\w+)\(\)\{\})*\s*(?<-b>\})
```

when applied to

```
class A { B(){} C(){} }
```

only return

```
class: A
method: C
```

?

In my opinion it should also match B.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use captures if you have repeated groups.

```
Match m = Regex.Match("class A { B(){} C(){} }", @"class (?<class>\w+) (?<b>\{)(?:\s*(?<method>\w+)\(\)\{\})*\s*(?<-b>\})");
var methods = m.Groups["method"].Captures;
for (int i = 0; i < methods.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(methods[i].Value);
```

Output:

```
B
C
```

[C# Demo](http://rextester.com/YJHA2342)

Additionally: You cannot use `-b` as group name, change it to `b_end` or similar, otherwise you will not capture `b` and `-b` groups.

```
class (?<class>\w+) (?<b_start>\{)(?:\s*(?<method>\w+)\(\)\{\})*\s*(?<b_end>\})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: I don't actually want to capture b and -b, I just want to use them to match braces.